# Is there a difference in Obj['var'] and Obj.prototype.var?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am not quite sure how to state the question in word terms as I do not know what to call this -> `Obj['var] = something`.

I believe the title sums it up, is there any difference in declaring a variable or function of an object in those two different manners, or are they the same, different ways of doing the same thing.

**EDIT:**

An Example of my code:

Sorry for the confusing variable names, watch out for the capital characters :/

```
buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
Buttons = new Button_Objs();

for (i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++){
    button = buttons[i];
    Buttons['button' + i] = new Button(button);
}
```

---

```
var Button = function(elem){
    this.buttonType = elem.getAttribute('button-type');
    if (this.buttonType = 'safety'){
        constructSafetyButton(elem, this);
    }
}
```

---

```
function constructSafetyButton(elem, button){

    button['setState'] = function(state){//do something}
```

### }

I get yelled at by browsers when trying to use `button.prototype.setState = func...`

Comment: `obj.var` is the same as `obj['var']`. Playing with the prototype is different.

Comment: A prototype is just an object.

It's any object that another object uses as it's prototype.

Comment: *"I get yelled at by browsers when trying to use...*": Because `button` is not a function. Only functions have a `.prototype` property by default.

Comment: @FelixKling I am quite confused, then what exactly is `button`? And what would make it a function?

Comment: It's an object. `Button` with a capital `B` is a function in your example. You are calling `new Button()`, so  inside the function, `this` refers to an empty object inheriting from `Button.prototype`. That object are you then passing to `constructSafetyButton` where you refer to it as `button`.

Comment: @FelixKling So in order to use prototype, I have to not use `this`? What would I use instead to refer to the object?

Comment: You don't have to use prototype at all. Your usage of `this` is correct. If you wanted to attach properties to the prototype so that they are shared across instances (that's what it is for), you might have to restructure your code a bit. But that depends on what `this` is doing exactly. And maybe using prototype is not suitable in your situation anyway. I recommend that you read the links in my answers to learn a bit more about prototypal inheritance in JavaScript and constructor functions (and maybe objects) and then decide what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Obj['var'] = ...` (and `Obj.var = ...` for that matter) assigns a property to the object which `Obj` is referring to.

Example:

```
var obj = {};
obj['foo'] = 'bar';
// or obj.foo = 'bar';
console.log(obj.foo); // shows 'bar'
```

---

`Obj.prototype.var = ...` will most likely throw an error, unless `Obj` is a **function**. Functions have a special property called `prototype` from which all new instances inherit when the function is called as constructor function, i.e. called with the `new` keyword.

Example:

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.bar = 'baz';

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar); // shows 'baz'
```

Since functions themselves are objects too, you can assign properties to them as well

```
Foo.someProp = 'someVal';
```

but this does not influence instances created by `Foo` at all. New instances only inherit from `Foo.prototype`:

```
console.log(foo.someProp); // shows undefined
```

---

While both statements assign properties to objects (in this regard they are "the same"), the outcome is entirely different.

If you want to learn more about prototypal inheritance in JavaScript, have a look at [MDN - Details of the Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) and [MDN - Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Answer (score 3):

Based on the question in the title, no they are different.

```
Obj['var'] = something
```

is equivalent to this:

```
Obj.var = something;
```

Which is entirely different from setting a value on the `prototype` property of some object.

```
Obj.prototype.var = somthing
```

Comment: Hmm, I may have worded my questions poorly. When creating a new Variable or Function in the object is there a difference when using `prototype.newFunction` or `Obj['newFunction']`?

Comment: @MichaelMitchell Can you update your question with more examples or rephrase? That sounds like what I tried to answer. Is your question about usage of square brackets vs quotes, or about prototypes, or both.